# What is the plural form of Boa Constrictor?

Tags: grammatical-number, parenthetical-plural

My friend said that it is 'boae constrictor' since 'boa' is in Latin. But I told him that first of all, it would be more correct as 'boae constrictor(s)', but the actual correct form is 'boa constrictors'. Which one is it?

Comment: Hello, Boa. Collins, Wiktionary, Britannica, [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=boa+constrictors+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l5j46i3i143i362j0i3i66i143i362l2.2751799314j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) etc give the plural form. As 'boa constrictor' is an English term, it is not constrained to echo Latin pluralisation conventions (and doesn't).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My answer is better than yours, both in detail as well as in placement.

Comment: @tchrist It concerns me that so obviously off-topic a question is answered at all by a senior contributor. By all means open a related on-topic question, asking whether there is any rhyme/reason that explains the form of the easily found accepted plural.

Comment: The OP's question is asking about the English plural of an English name for a particular snake. The OP suggests the correct plural: It follows adder -> adders. That the OP makes a mistake in the aside about Latin is neither here nor there.

Answer (score 5):

**Boa constrictors**.

In English, compound nouns usually add the plural suffix to the last word (see [Collins Dictionary](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/how-do-you-form-the-plural-of-compound-nouns-in-english)). So, for example, you would say *seat belts* and not *seats belt*.

There are a few exceptions, like *woman driver* / *women drivers* or *attorney general* and *attorneys general*. With the latter, the head is the first word and not the second ([Transparent, "Head-First Plural Nouns](https://blogs.transparent.com/english/head-first-plural-nouns/)"). That said, even with a head-first form, you'll often see the last word pluralized: see *poet laureates* ([Ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poet%20laureates%2C%20poets%20laureate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), where the plural appears on the first or the second at about the same rate) or *whiskey sours* ([Ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whiskeys%20sour%2C%20whiskey%20sours&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), where "whiskeys sour" is too rare for the corpus).

Boa constrictor conforms to the more general pattern no matter what its head is. With a few [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) searches for *boa*, *boas*, and *boae*, the only standard form with *constrictor* and *constrictors* is *boa*. *Boas* mainly results in references to Franz Boas, the famous anthropologist, and related key terms. *Boae* doesn't appear in the corpus.

Comment: In a compound, it's not the last word, but rather the head that generally gets pluralized. That is often the last word, but don't let the secretaries general catch you! In Boa constrictor, one could argue that boa, being the head, should get pluralized instead of constrictor. There are arguments to pluralize the latter, but not because "the last word gets pluralized

Comment: @oerkelens I will modify my answer to explain that as an *exception*. I prefer the practical explanation to one where I'd have to at once explain how to identify a head and why identifying the head isn't useful for *boa constrictor*. Many compounds exist where the "head" is the first word but the last is pluralized; even for *attorney general*, *whiskey sour*, and *poet laureate*, you're likely to see *attorney generals*, *whiskey sours*, and [*poet laureates*], including in published writing.

Comment: I'm tempted to write a related on-topic question. At least include your 'comment' as a footnote to the answer; I don't remember this being stated elsewhere, and it would be a pity to lose it.

Comment: *Attorneys general* and *poets laureate* are common enough, but I suggest *nobody* ever says/writes ***two whisk[e]ys sour***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Plus I imagine people analyse *constrictor* to be the head and *boa* to be the modifier here following normal English word order rather than that of scientific nomenclature. You can tell it has become a common noun rather than a proper noun because they stop using italics and correct capitalization.  :)

Answer (score 0):

## Inﬂectional afflictions

Scientific names used in biological nomenclature come ***already inflected*** for case, number, and gender under the esoteric rules of Latin grammar. These official names are locked down by the original naming act that establishes them, and you **must not alter** these word-forms to meet any inflectional requirements from the surrounding grammatical context when used in sentences, no matter what language you are writing in.

That is why when one *Homo sapiens* marries another, you do **not** have a couple of *Homines sapientes*; you merely have two members of the species *Homo sapiens*.  And when you buy ten Poet’s narcissus bulbs, you still have ten *Narcissus poeticus* bulbs to plant, not ten *Narcissi poetici* let alone ten *Narcissi poeticorum*.

In his 2014 book, *The Naming of the Shrew*, English mycologist and taxonomist John Wright writes:

> A scientific name consists of two Latinised words in the general form of noun and qualifier – as in ‘brown duck’, ‘Johnson’s lizard’, or ‘elephant shrew’. The genus (duck) is the noun and specific epithet (brown) the qualifier.
>
> The generic name is usually a noun (*Sorex*: ‘shrew’) or several words that may or may not be nouns joined together to look like one (*Glycophagus*: ‘sugar eater’), or, at the very least, a word in which the noun is implicit, as in adjectivally inclined names, such as *Scabiosus*: ‘rough [thing]’.
>
> [...]
>
> ### *Inﬂection*
>
> As already noted, the two words that make up a binomial are required to be grammatically correct. [...] A word ending depends on case, gender, number, and declension. There are six standard cases in Latin, although mercifully only nominative and genitive are used in biological nomenclature. [...] Like many languages, Latin is afﬂicted by gender and gender endings for objects and concepts that display no sexual identity whatsoever (this disease is largely absent from English but in Latin achieves its most virulent form). Nouns can be masculine, feminine, or neuter. Number is, of course, an inﬂection familiar to English speakers.

These formal requirements are prickly but strict. It is not unheard of for biologists to make grammatical errors in agreement when they create a new binomial. These alone are subsequently corrected through an appeals board, and even then the originals may be conserved in that they may not ever be re-used.

You aren’t allowed to change the inflection because that would be a different thing altogether. Our hypothetically inﬂected *Narcissi poeticorum* would work out to the daffodils of the poets in English, but they would not be several of copies of the Poet’s daffodil, which has a scientific name whose built-in number inﬂection is pre-determined and inﬂexibly set upon the creation of its name: *Narcissus poeticus*.

## Dispelling the enchantment

Every now and then a scientific name may enter into common usage unchanged from its original Latinized form: *Homo sapiens, Boa constrictor, Tyrannosaurus rex, Ginkgo biloba*, and *Aloe vera*. When this happens, we stop following the strict rules of scientific nomenclature, dispensing with the mandatory italic typeface and capitalization rules under which the generic name must always be capitalized and the specific name must never be capitalized.

This breaks the spell holding the Latinized words inviolate, allowing you to use normal English morphology again, treating them like compound nouns if both parts are used. This is really much easier, because now you can have all the tyrannosaurs or tyrannosaurus rexes (**not** Latin *reges*!), along with all the boas or boa constrictors, that suit your fancy.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the plural has to be "*boa constrictor**s***".

[image]

[boa constrictors](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boa%20constrictors%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Comment: You plotted *boas constrictors* not OP’s *boae constrictor*.

Comment: OP is proposing *boae constrictor(s)* as a plural form.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Right, this should be added.

Comment: Your search did not separate out scientific names from common names. Common names are not automatically capitalized or set in italic, but scientific names are: it must be *Genus species* never *genus species* nor *Genus Species*.